# Getting inflate exception in Android

Tags: android, layout, inflate

I am very new to Android development and I am facing a little problem here.
I want to create a custom TextView class by extending TextView and use this class in ListView(every row of ListView contains this class' object).

I have created my custom class like this

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView{

Context context;
Paint mPaint;
String text;

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}


private void init(){
    setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    mPaint.setTextSize(16);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {

    this.text = (String) text;
    super.setText(text, type);
}


@Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);       
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int reqWidth;
    int reqHeight;

    // width & height mode
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    // specified width & height
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    // find out Width based on widthMode
    if(widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        // set user specified Width
        reqWidth = widthSize;
    else
        // find out the total pixel size required for first and last text
        reqWidth = (int)(mPaint.measureText(text)) ;

    // find out Height based on heightMode
    if(heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        // set user specified Height
        reqHeight = heightSize;
    else
        // get the default height of the Font
        reqHeight = (int) mPaint.getTextSize();

    // set the calculated width and height of your drawing area
    setMeasuredDimension(reqWidth, reqHeight);
}
}
```

and for each row ofmy ListView I have created a xml structure consisting of a TextView,My custom class, and an image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:gravity="left|center"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:paddingBottom="5px"
 android:paddingTop="5px" 
 android:paddingLeft="5px">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:background="@drawable/bg" 
 android:textColor="#FFFF00"
 android:text="hi"/>

<!--<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10px" 
android:text="hi"/>

-->
<com.example.CustomTextView  
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="50px"

/>   


<ImageView android:id = "@+id/image"
android:src="@drawable/icon"
android:layout_width = "50dip"
android:layout_height = "50dip"

/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

In the Adapter class of my ListView I am retrieving the structure like this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
         convertView =  mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);

         convertView.setMinimumHeight(80);

         holder = new ViewHolder();
         holder.text = (TextView) convertView
         .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);


         holder.text2 = (CustomTextView) convertView
         .findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
}
```

But I am getting inflate exception on

```
 convertView =  mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
```

However, if instead of my custom view , I add a simple textView in layout.xml(layout structure of each row of listview) then everything works fine

I have searched forums but I am not getting what i am doing wrong.

Please help me in this case.

Comment: could you show the complete error message please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the cause of your error, but your constructors call the `init()` function, and the init function uses that `mPaint` variable.

The `mPaint` variable is declared as `Paint mPaint;`, but it is never instantiated, so it is null. You'll be getting a `nullPointerException` there i think

I don't know how the constructor of `mPaint` works, but you need to do something like this before you can use it:

```
mPaint = new Paint mPaint();
```

edit: ah: i'm seeing that your `onDraw()` *does* use `Paint paint = new Paint();`. But that might be a bit too late?

Comment: Thanx a lot. This was the only problem . thanx a lot figuring it out

Comment: you're not supposed to instantiate variables inside the ondraw method because it is called infinitely, it will clog up your memory